# Unicode symbol that represents "download"

Tags: unicode

I'm searching for a Unicode character that I can use to symbolize downloads. [DOWNWARDS BLACK ARROW](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=11007&number=128) (U+2B07, ⬇) looks quite good, but it doesn't seem to be available in default fonts: *[Browser Test Page for Unicode Character 'DOWNWARDS BLACK ARROW' (U+2B07)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2b07/browsertest.htm)*

Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could use ↓ ([U+2193](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8590&number=128), DOWNWARDS ARROW). It is available in the [Arial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arial) font.

To see a complete list, run *charmap.exe* from Windows. It will show you all available Unicode characters.

Comment: this one is more common `"\u21E9"` === **`"⇩"`**.

Comment: For downloads I prefer `2B73`, the ⭳ symbol.

Comment: For some reason 2B73 has abnormal padding in at least some fonts. 2913 `⤓` worked better in my case.

Comment: HTML ```<u>↓</u>``` worked fine in my case

Answer (score 23):

Check site *[Test for Unicode support in Web browsers](http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/arrows.html)* out. You might find what you need.

For example this: ⇓

Although an image would be a better solution in my opinion.

Comment: ⇓ ([DOWNWARDS DOUBLE ARROW](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/21d3/)) or: ⤓ ([DOWNWARDS ARROW TO BAR](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2913/)) / ↓ ([DOWNWARDS ARROW](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2193/)) / ↧ ([DOWNWARDS ARROW FROM BAR](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/21a7/)) / ⬇ ([DOWNWARDS BLACK ARROW](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2b07/)) / ⇩ ([DOWNWARDS WHITE ARROW](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/21e9/)) / ▼ ([BLACK DOWN-POINTING TRIANGLE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25bc/))

Comment: Some related emojis in case it helps anyone: ⬇️⤵️